# Styling Custom adapter for gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

**What I am trying to get** ::
< ***`I am trying to display same look on both landscape and portrait mode`***>

### [image]

---

**What i am currently having** ::
< ***Observe the `imageview`  looks differently in different orientation modes*** > height of the imageview is more in portrait mode

### [image][image]

---

**grid_single.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/eleven" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You mean you want the ImageView's to stretch/fill on height with the same margin as on width on portrait? (similar to Landscape view)

Comment: @ SuppressWarnings .....yes ., i want same look as i have shown in first snapshot for both orientation modes

Comment: Try to add 2 more items..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your ImageView xml to this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/eleven" >
</ImageView>
```

You have a good sample of different `android:scaleType` displays, and how they behave [here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this XML instead..

**grid_single.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/eleven" >
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```